# Capturing User who deleted record using CDC. SQL DYNAMICS AX

Tags: axapta, cdc

I want to Capture the Username who deleted the record . But CDC does not track who deleted record. Can you tell me how to acheieve this????

Comment: Try to show some investigations of you please.

Comment: I am working on Dynamics Ax , so we are trying to do audit using CDC. But we are unable to see who deleted the record in the cdc tracking tables. I tried some ways like i tried to do an update before delete so whenever we do an update the modified by field will be changed and then if its deleted the username will be same who deleted it. But it doesnot work. So i am looking for some workaround s or any other ways where i can get username who deleted the record using CDC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [database logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362089.aspx) for tracking specific types of changes to AX tables and fields. Changes that can be tracked include *insert*, *update*, *delete* or *rename key*. When you configure logging for a table or field, a record of any change to that table or field is stored in the database log table, `sysdatabaselog`, in the AX database.

You can use the **Logging database changes** wizard to set up database logging. The wizard provides a flexible way to set up logging for tables or fields.

1. Click **System administration > Setup > Database > Database log setup**. Click **New** to start the **Logging database changes** wizard.
2. Complete the wizard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually we are using Change Data Capture. So i need some way to get the username who deleted the record using change data capture only. is there a way?

Comment: According to Microsoft, CDC has not been designed to be an auditing feature (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/283707). If you want to capture the name of the AX user that deleted the record, you can use a standard AX feature - database logging. If I'm not mistaken, CDC logs only sequential number, sequence value, operation, and an update mask.

Comment: By the way, if CDC could capture the user name, wouldn't it then capture the AOS SQL Server user name instead of the actual AX user that deleted the record?

Comment: CDC doesnt capture the username. We are getting username from modifiedby field of AX table(as we are capruting modifiedby field in the ax table).

Comment: THanks for the reply.  But we are already using cdc as auditing feature , do you think will it be a good idea to use both database logging and cdc ? I dont find a way to capture who deleted the record. THats my only concern. Remaining all features are working fine using CDC.

Comment: Ok, I understand now how you are tracking the username for other operations. I've never used CDC with AX, but I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to set up database logging in AX to track only 'delete' operation where needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done using database log for capturing user who deleted it as you said. Its working . THanks.